# Shield gamma/X-ray/ultraviolet radiation without blocking radio waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, radioactivity

I was theoretically considering building an airtight enclosure that shielded the insides from gamma/X-ray/ultraviolet radiation but did not block radio waves (so that communication would not be interrupted). Is this physically possible?

Comment: Put the radio antenna outside the box with a shielded feed-through.

Answer (score 0):

Question seems to be a very interesting one.  I like to give only a guessed answer.  All light waves and radio waves are reflected at all possible places and they find some means to reach inside, if there is a possibility.  If it is completely closed, even low frequency radio waves find it difficult to reach the destination.  For example, it is difficult to communicate with submarines by using ordinary radio waves: https://www.naval-technology.com/features/featuredeep-secret-secure-submarine-communication-on-a-quantum-level/
The next link also provides some information about penetrating capacity of radio waves in this connection.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/346885522_Formula_for_Harmfulness_of_Cell_Phone_Waves_for_One_Type_of_Pollution